# Windows equavalent of pthread_sigmask()

Tags: linux, windows, pthreads, signals, posix

I am implementing a wrapper for the pthread functions that can be used in both Linux and Windows.

In Linux the function pthread_sigmask() allows the user the `BLOCK` or `UNBLOCK` signals that a thread can recieve.

[pthread_sigmask](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_sigmask)

I am unable to find an equavalent function in Windows for this.It would be great if someone could point me to an equavalent Windows function.

Comment: Windows doesn't have signals, so there's no need for a signal mask.

Comment: @Harry Johnston - certainly Windows does have some mechanism similar to signals.The questions is in Linux when you create a thread the signal from OS/another process can be received by parent thread or child thread.Is it same in Windows?

Comment: I am not aware of any mechanism in Windows that is sufficiently similar to UNIX signals to be relevant here.  If you have one in mind, you'll need to be specific.  Alternatively, if you'd like to choose a particular signal and explain what it does in UNIX, I can probably explain how you would do the same thing in Windows.

Comment: Somehow I can't see the POSIX thread model being mapped to the Windows thread model all that easily. Why *exactly* do you want to do this? Any particular reason for not using an existing threading library?

Comment: I think this is a brilliant idea. There exists an implementation as part of cygwin. If we somehow could extract this function, we have a good basis for pthreads on Windows. Many of the remaining functions have a 1-1 map to C11 threads (not to be confused with C++11 threads)